# Load and link obj files at Runtime in C/C++ (JIT)

Tags: c++, c, llvm, jit

I'm searching for a C or C++ library which can load and link obj files (doesn't matter if ELF or obj) dynamicly at runtime. I spend some time searching for such library, but my results weren't successful.

What I tried:

**LLVM**:
Currently my best solution! I used Clang to generate .obj files in the bytecode format of LLVM and used its JIT functions to dynamic load and execute the function. But, the LLVM is huge and my PC at home hasn't the power to compile the complete LLVM just for the JIT. Also I encountered some problems with relocation overflows or not implemented relocation types.

**libjit**:
I read, that it can load .elf files and link them too. But sadly, I couldn't compile it for windows, so I couldn't try.

**Nanojit and NativeJit**:
It seems like they don't support JITting an object file.

So... What can I do? Do I have to stick around with the LLVM? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to acomplish? From what you wrote, `dlopen` would be enough, but you probably mean something different.

Comment: You can't load and link `.obj` files dynamically. That's what _shared libraries_ (`.dll`'s) are for.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are different.  Some compilers use *name mangling* to support C++ overloading of functions.  The C compiler doesn't do this.  Your shared library interface needs to know whether or not to use name mangling.

Comment: I don't want to use shared libraries.

I want to JIT an object file and resolve the references to the functions at runtime. With LLVM it's like this:

You compile (don't link) you .cpp file to the bytecode of LLVM. Then you load this object file at runtime. The JIT will extract all Segments and call a function for undefined references like when you use printf. Now you have the chance to give the JIT an address for the function and in the end you have a working function. With the LLVM it is working, but it's huge. So I'm searching for alternatives

Comment: Probably [GCC JIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/JIT)  doing something like this.

Comment: On Windows you will need MinGW64 from [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that an analogy that can be taken as a 1st approach is that the `.bc` (LLVM bitcode) is similar to an `.o` (or `.obj`) file in that it is just the translation of C++ code to an intermediate language, and tht it can contain references to functions not defined in it, to be searched in libraries.

And that the JIT-ted code is similar to a DLL, in the sense that it will be linked dynamically to the executable where it will run in.

You need not to compile LLVM -- you can download the binaries for LLVM and assorted utilities (like `clang`) from [LLVM Download Page](http://releases.llvm.org/)